# PYTHON + SELENIUM - Need get an element of html by selenium and save it to a variable

Tags: python, selenium, selector

Just as the title

I need to get an element by queryselectorall because ID, NAMES, CLASSES are generated randomly every time page loads.

So using js I can do it using this

```
document.querySelectorAll(".portal-category")[2]
```

But I need to work with that element into selenium (python), I know there are some methods

```
By.CLASS_NAME
By.ID
etc...
```

but there is not option for "querySelectorAll", so any solution? Can someone help me please?
need something like this

```
myelement = driver.find_element_by_query_all('Xconditions')
```

Comment: If you want to grab the 2nd element with the class portal-category . Just driver.find_elements(BY.CSS_SELECTOR,”.portal-category”)[2] should work for you.

Comment: thankyou this work for me
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".portal-category")[2]
thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

```py
tags = {tag.name for tag in soup.find_all()}
  
for tag in tags:
    for i in soup.find_all( tag ):
        if i.has_attr( "class" ):
            # Do checks here
```

You could use something like this to find all of the attributes with class. And then you could just check what the class is.